# Is user Custom parameters allowed with twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using Twilio service to send messages to different types of users in my application. Now the message logs show all messages listing properly, but can I add an optional parameter to identify a different set of messages sent to different users. 
Is user Custom parameters allowed with Twilio message logs to identify/filter Messages based on this parameter?

If my way of thinking is wrong, is there any solution to categorize or identify a specific group of messages sent to a particular group of people?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mobile_numbers); $i++) 
            {
                $mobile_number = $mobile_numbers[$i];
                $otp_message_result = json_decode(send_text_message($mobile_number, $custom_message));
                $msg_sid = $otp_message_result -> sid;
                $msg_status = $otp_message_result -> status;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your code sample is supposed to represent here, can you explain a bit more? What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @philnash 
While sending message can I send one extra parameter like customer_id so that I can filter the message logs in Twilio based on this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are no custom fields available within the Twilio API for saving your own data to.

If you want to [find all the messages sent to one telephone number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message?code-sample=code-list-all-messages&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x) then you can filter by that number, like this:

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "your_account_sid";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$phone_number = PHONE_NUMBER;

// Loop over the list of messages and echo a property for each one
foreach ($client->messages->read(array("To" => $phone_number)) as $message) {
    echo $message->body;
}
```

If you need to be any more specific, then I recommend you save the SIDs of the messages that you sent to each user to your own database.